# Why are my images too big for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova

I started a Photoshop document with the following set up:

width: 640px
height: 960px
Resolution: 326 pixels/inch
The images are taken directly from that file.

I am using phonegap to build an application. Whenever I test it, it makes my image far too large for the iphone screen. I'm not using a viewport or resizing anything. Please help!

Some of you were asking for my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" />     


    <!-- iPad/iPhone specific css below, add after your main css >
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" type="text/css" />        
    -->
    <!-- If your application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">

<div class="wrapper">

<img src="img/iPhone/Welcome.png" class="header" />

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not like I know phonegap, but posting a screenshot or some source code would help everyone here, I guess.

Comment: What is the end size of the images that you save? The 326 Pixels per inch may be the problem - Photoshop may store the files with a much larger pixel size because of it

Comment: try adding `@2x` at the end of the file. Example: `supermegacoolpicture@2x.png`

Comment: i had the same problem with my web once, using 300ppi images. try reducing the resolution to 90ppi. resolutions that high are only good for printing

Answer (score 3):

Just create images with 640x960 size don't set 326 ppi its not needed. Just go with default.

Comment: Even at 72 the images still appear much larger.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set that resolution... To create iPhone app UI in Photoshop, use these settings:

**iPhone 3G/3GS - iPod**
Width: 320px
Height: 480px
Resoluzion: 72px/inch
Color Method: RGB 8bit
Pixel Ratio: Square Pixels

**iPhone 4**
Width: 640px
Height: 960px
Resolution: 72px/inch
Color Method: RGB 8bit
Pixel Ratio: Square Pixels

When you save your bigger images (retina display), remember to name them with the same name of the smaller and add `@2x` before .png

Comment: I've done the exact specs you have here but it still renders the images too large. I even looked up the image in xcode and it's saying its sized at 640x960 and is 72 pixels/inch. I also tried the @2x thing but that doesn't seem to be working either. Any thoughts

Comment: I don't know phonegap and unfortunately I can't help you about this... I use these settings every day and I've never had problems...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're using a "retina" size image, you still need to specify the size (resolution) as 320x480 in your CSS (and config.xml)

If you think about, although there are more pixels packed in, the screen size is still the same. Also, it makes further sense as your image is displaying too big when you set it to the larger, retina, size.